# PySpark DataFrame - extracting parameter and value using regexp

Tags: regex, pyspark, databricks

We have a spark dataframe that stores string values.
There is a need to extract parameter name (given in *{}* ) with its value using dataframe transformation. The name of parametr is not fixed - each row can store different params.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

| Pattern | Sample input | Expected result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://{accountName}.queue.core.windows.net/?restype=service&timeout={timeout} | https://stackoverflow.queue.core.windows.net/?restype=service&timeout=20 | {accountName="stackoverflow", timeout=20} |
| https://{accountName}.queue.core.windows.net/?restype=service | https://customer-academy.queue.core.windows.net/?restype=service | {accountName="customer-academy"} |

Code to create a spark data frame:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("https://{accountName}.queue.core.windows.net/?restype=service&timeout={timeout}", "https://stackoverflow.queue.core.windows.net/?restype=service&timeout=20"),
    ("https://{accountName}.queue.core.windows.net/?restype=service&timeout", "https://customer-academy.queue.core.windows.net/?restype=service")
    ], 
    StructType([StructField("pattern", StringType(), True), StructField("sample_input", StringType(), True)])
)
```

Comment: You can use UDF(User Defined Function) to fetch the required values from the pattern.

Comment: UDF is not efficient enough therefore we are looking for a solution that uses DF transformation only. Is it possible to use caputure group name`?P<name>`- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups @Zero

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`regexp_extract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html) function from the PySpark SQL functions.

The syntax will be like:

```
import re
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn('accountName', F.regexp_extract(F.col(), re.compile('https\:\/\/([A-z0-9\-]+)\.queue\.core\.windows\.net\/\?restype\=service\&timeout\=(\d+)'), 1)) # to take the first group i.e. account name

df = df.withColumn('timeout', F.regexp_extract(F.col(), re.compile('https\:\/\/([A-z0-9\-]+)\.queue\.core\.windows\.net\/\?restype\=service\&timeout\=(\d+)'), 2)) # to take the second group i.e. timeout
```